# Laravel Trying to get property of non-object inside map function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

can anyone please gime some clues or explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
->map( function( $q ) use ( $idEventFlow ) {
        $idEventFlow = $idEventFlow->where( 'idProcessSubtask', $q->idProcessSubtask )->first();
        // dd( $q->idStatus = $idEventFlow->idStatus );
        $q->idStatus = $idEventFlow->idStatus;
        return $q;
    });
```

> dd( $q->idStatus = $idEventFlow->idStatus )

gives me the expected result!!!

but the function itself is returning

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: because calling `dd` in a loop is stopping this on the first iteration ... what line does it say is the offending line?

Comment: $idEventFlow is null one of the iterations. dd() stops at the first iteration. You have to check if $idEventFlow null or not before accessing any property

Comment: that's right, stupid me... the problem is that every $idEventFlow don't have a $q->idProcessSubtask... my bad
you rock guys...

Answer (score 0):

sometimes when you are too close to a problem, you can't see the solution, thanks to [@ziad-adeela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13229814/ziad-adeela) & [@lagbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2109233/lagbox) for help me with this silly problem.

```
    ->map( function( $q ) use ( $idEventFlow ) {
        $idEventFlow = $idEventFlow->where( 'idProcessSubtask', $q->idProcessSubtask )->first();
        if( $idEventFlow ) {
            $q->idStatus = $idEventFlow->idStatus;
            $q->name = $idEventFlow->name;
            $q->icon = $idEventFlow->icon;
            $q->colorHex = $idEventFlow->colorHex;
        }
        return $q;
    });
```